# Compose Java-8-Functional-Interface

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, functional-interface

I have an Java-8-FunctionalInterface like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface A {
    void doIt ();
}
```

The `Function`-Interface provides an `compose`-Method. I want to use it, to reduce an stream of `A` like this:

```
Stream<A> as;
A composed = as.reduce (() -> {}, Function::compose);
```

As result I want to have a function of `A`, which calls on each `A` of the Stream its method `doIt`.

```
composed.doIt (); // Executes every doIt ()
```

But because A **is not** a implementer of `Function`, the method reference `Function::compose` is not possible there. I cannot extend from `Function` (or `Supplier`), because then I would have two abstract methods (my own and the one from `Function`).

What can I do, to make it possible, to compose my functions of `A`?

Comment: `do` is not a valid identifier in java

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - do you simply want to `as.forEach(A::do)`?

Comment: @fabian: I correct this, I reduced the code two much ;-)
But that wasn't the problem.

Comment: I want to have an object of A. Later I want to call it with a.doIt (). It's execution should lead to a call to every doIt of all A of the Stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reason why the `compose` method has to come from the `Function` interface. For your case the `Function` interface is not appropriate as `Function` has a return value (rather than `void`) and it’s `compose` method is intended to feed the result of one function into the next.

Just make your own `compose` method:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface A {
  void doIt ();
  default A compose(A next) {
      return () -> { doIt(); next.doIt(); };
  }
}
```

Then you can do as intended:

```
Stream<A> as=…;
A composed = as.reduce (() -> {}, A::compose);
```

---

Note that since your interface has the same semantic as `Runnable` you could even make it a sub-interface of `Runnable` to allow mixing of `Runnable`s and `A`s:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface A extends Runnable {
    default void doIt() { run(); }
    default A compose(Runnable next) {
      return () -> { doIt(); next.run(); };
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i didn't thought of that.
But I would expect Java to be capable of see that A is an FunctionalInterface and when needed, see it as an implementation of Function, so I don't need to repeat the implementation of compose.

Comment: @F. Böller: but your interface is not a `Function`. A `Function` has a `T->R` signature while your interface has a `()->()` signature. They are not compatible.

Comment: +1 This is fundamentally correct, as Java is statically typed, and its functional interfaces are statically typed, so it follows that an operator that performs functional composition also has to be statically typed. A minor point: the convention used in `Function` is that `f.compose(g)` is analogous to f(g()) which applies `g` before `f`. The `andThen` method applies them the other way around.